# Is there an in-universe name for the "Vulcan Salute"?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, terminology

I was about to ask someone about their usage of a particular hand gesture, which is similar to the way Vulcans use their "Salute" alongside the standard greeting of "Live long, and prosper" when I realized I don't know the "real" name for the "Vulcan Salute".

I'm aware that it is derived from a gesture made during a Jewish Priestly benediction, but I'm wondering if there's an in-universe name for the Vulcans' usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In non-canon land, one single novel names the salute the [Ta'al](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ta%27al).

<sub>(The name is not familiar to me, so within canon I agree with DVK - I recall no name for it in the live-action TV series or movies)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be pronounced "tah-ahl" or "tay-ahl"...  Any Vulcan speakers around?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan_salute) - as well as extensive Googling - there doesn't seem to be an in-universe name aside from "Vulcan Salute". It appears that the "Live long and prosper" phrase has more significance than the salute itself.

Comment: Also, according to same general source, 'Live Long and Prosper' translates to, '"Dif tor heh smusma.'